# How to optimize service calls

Tags: ros, optimization, ros-kinetic, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to optimize my code so I was measuring how long different parts of ROS process take. Specifically

```
rospy.wait_for_service(rospy.get_param('~service_name'))
```

always seems to take little over 2 ms

```
service = rospy.ServiceProxy(rospy.get_param('~service_name'), MySrv)
```

always seems to take little under 1 ms

```
resp = service(MySrvRequest())
```

always seems to take little over 1 ms

This all causes the one service call to result in about 4 ms of delay and I want to get my program to 1 ms precision. What are the variables that effect how long those service calls take? Can I adjust the setting somewhere to make it faster?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327668/how-to-optimize-service-calls/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-04**:
Service calls use the networking functions to communicate with different nodes. So their speed is effected by many factors. If the service server node was on a different computer These numbers could be much higher! If you really need speed and consistency that much then you'll have to try and merge functionality into a single node (binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few things to note:

- you're trying to achieve a 1kHz loop rate with a Python script: not impossible, but certainly not the first combination of runtime environment and performance requirements I'd choose. Have you considered the amount of jitter this is going to experience?
- using parameters is always good (improves reusability of your code), but in this case for your `service` variable to be initialised you're incurring the overhead of communicating with the parameter server by using `get_param(..)` there. That's a full XML-RPC session setup, communication (ie: transmit and receive), (de)serialisation and teardown just to read a single parameter.
- you don't appear to be using a [persistent connection](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Services#Persistent_Connections). That causes `rospy` to *always* do a full lookup and rebinding of the `ServiceProxy` upon invoking it. That is a lot of overhead as the network stack and multiple other nodes are involved (ie: service server *and* the master).

And from this:

> This all causes the one service call to result in about 4 ms of delay and I want to get my program to 1 ms precision.

I get two impressions:

1. you're executing this piece of code in an inner / performance critical loop
2. you're using services for something they are not really suited for

If my first impression is correct: don't do that. If you must, only invoke the already initialised (ie: bound) service call in your loop. The rest should be done in the initialisation phase of your script.

For the second: I would personally not use services for something like this, but that is of course your choice and would depend on many things we do not know.

Finally: in #q328017 you mention the word "real-time". You're most likely already aware, but a standard Python interpreter is not a deterministic runtime environment. `rospy` is incapable of deterministic execution, and the TCP/IP based communication system used is also non-deterministic. If "real-time" was meant to say "fast enough", then it's probably possible, but it won't be deterministic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) on 2022-12-16**:
For completeness: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Services#persistent_connections shows how to enable persistent connections in rospy while your impressive answer links to roscpp